# Is Thermal radiation emitted by a blackbody some photons

Tags: thermal-radiation, sun

If a blackbody absorbs all radiation
and emits some due to it's heat, then is the thermal radiation actually some photons that are not in the visible region?
Can there be a blackbody that emits thermal radiation that are in the visible spectrum?

I heard that black bodies are black

Comment: Have you never seen something that's so hot that it glows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you added the tag "Sun" to your question! Yes, the surface of the Sun can be thought of as (approximately) a blackbody - the surface brightness of a blackbody (which *is* "thermal radiation") is proportional to its temperature to the power of four. Thermal radiation in the visible spectrum is emitted significantly by objects that are at temperatures of $>3000$ K (roughly speaking) and the "surface" of the Sun is at 5800 K.

Blackbodies are called that because they absorb all radiation incident upon them, not because they don't emit visible radiation.

Comment: thanks..........

Answer (score 1):

Yes, thermal radiation IS photons. All matter with a temperature greater than absolute zero emits photons. All electromagnetic radiation is made of individual photons.

Comment: So if i leave something in space it's gonna slowly loose it's temp to 0

Comment: am i emmiting photons right now if i'm sitting in a dark room

Comment: @user49791 yes you are emitting billions of photons